# What does the associative location of "friends" in the Facebook Friends tab indicate?

Tags: facebook

I have seen some very interesting patterns on the Facebook friends tab. It seems as though there is some sort of pattern in terms of date added or perhaps friends with similar social connections. Does anyone know what the sorting methodology for the "All Friends" tab within the "Friends" tab may be?

I used to think that it was something along the lines of age of a friendship, but now I'm no longer convinced of this.

Here is an image to help illustrate the question better as per request:
[image]